# ReportViewer Drillthrough "Stopped" Working

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

We're using Reportviewer and rdlc files in our application. I had drillthroughs working fine and we put the app on the backburner to work on other projects. Now that the Users wanted a new build I revisited the app and tested with a new password in the connection string. To my surprise the Drillthroughs no longer work. To my further surprise I can't even click on the textbox that fires the drillthrough. I checked TFS and there have been no changes to the Report definition or the ViewModel that handles the Drillthrough. All I changed were the connection strings.

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to figure this one out I'll be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out if anyone else is interested. I installed Visual Studio SP1 which apparently [causes a few issues with ReportViewer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864).

Answer (score 0):

Hi we have had the same problem and finally found a hotfix which works. You only need to download the file VS10SP1-KB2549864-x86.exe . Install and try again. Should work.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=37409

Comment: Yup, the MS KB I linked to above has the download link as well.